# Show Remaining Work rollup value in TFS 2012 PBI

Tags: tfs

In TFS 2012, is it possible to show a field on a Product Backlog Item that represents the total Remaining Work for all of the child Tasks?

I've tried to add the Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork field right to the Work Item Type layout, but that doesn't actually make sense because how does it know where to roll up from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. You have to custom code it. This article (and others on this blog) can get you started if you want to go that route.

[link](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=336)

Comment: Obviously this article is for 2010.  Do you know for sure if the same process is still required for 2012?

Comment: I have not implemented this, exactly, but I have done some work with TFS 2012 API and most of the 2010 stuff has been applicable. I would assume (horrible, I know) that the implementation is at the least very similar.

Comment: Instead of custom coding it you can try use TFS Aggregator - http://tfsaggregator.codeplex.com/ however the developer is stuck on 2010 so hasn't had the chance to test it, chances are it will work but the machine will require team explorer 2010 installed, or recompiled against 2012 dlls since it is a plugin (can't load both versions in same app domain)

Comment: I released the 2012 version of TFS Aggregator recently.

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but still if anyone wants a simple answer, here is the latest update on the matter...

For Agile template its a direct property (Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate), for scrum you will need to change the WIT xml as described in the link below.

```
<FIELD name="Original Estimate" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate" type="Double" reportable="measure" formula="sum">
    <HELPTEXT>Initial value for Remaining Work - set once, when work begins</HELPTEXT>
</FIELD>
<FIELD name="Completed Work" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork" type="Double" reportable="measure" formula="sum">
    <HELPTEXT>The number of units of work that have been spent on this task</HELPTEXT>
</FIELD>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn769080.aspx